# Change Data type in the RxJava2 chain

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android, reactivex

I am new to RxJava2 and its methods.
I need to change the data type which is emitted from an Observable.

Say, I have a data class like below.

```
data class SomeClass (val type: String)
```

An API returns `ArrayList<SomeClass>`, this works fine on the current implementation using RxJava2 and RxAndroid.

```
apiService.getPrice(code)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(singleObserver)
```

I have to change/transform the data from `ArrayList<SomeClass> to HashMap<someClassObject.type, ArrayList<SomeClass>>`. I am trying operators to make this happen, but no operator will allow changing the datatype being observed.

Transform based on:

```
Consumer<ArrayList<SomeClass>> { response ->
                    val mapped = HashMap<String, ArrayList<SomeClass>>()
                    response.forEach { someClassObj ->
                        val type = someClassObj.type!!
                        if (mapped.containsKey(type)) {
                            mapped[district]?.add(someClassObj)

                        } else {
                            val list = ArrayList<SomeClass>()
                            list.add(someClassObj)
                            mapped[type] = list
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I am thinking to use two different observables, in which Observable data #2 is based on the response of Observable data #1 (`ArrayList<SomeClass>`). But, I am not sure if this works. Any better or efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `map(Function)` with that code snippet you showed.

Comment: tried map(), but not working.

Comment: "not working" is not very helpful to diagnose your problem. Please provide more details on how you tried it and what was the outcome: compilation error, wrong data printed, etc.

Comment: @akarnokd: Yes, my bad. I am sorry, I should have given more information on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `map`:

```
apiService.getPrice(code)
        .map { response ->
            val mapped = HashMap<String, ArrayList<SomeClass>>()
            response.forEach { someClassObj ->
                val type = someClassObj.type!!
                if (mapped.containsKey(type)) {
                    mapped[district]?.add(someClassObj)
                } else {
                    val list = ArrayList<SomeClass>()
                    list.add(someClassObj)
                    mapped[type] = list
                }
            }
            mapped
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(singleObserver);
```

Comment: Vote up: `map` operator is used to change the content of observable data. This is absolutely the correct answer to the question. :)

Comment: When I tried using map operator, I forgot to return the value from the map lambda block. This was resulting in "unable to change the datatype from source to required one". Thank you! :)